# how to solve jpa and hibernate one to one annotion with doSecondPass Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hi I am writing simple code that insert data into two tables using jpa and Hibernate 3.2 version.My inetention is to save Employee details in two tables i.e Employee which contains employeeId which is primary key that is manually assigned assigned value  and Employee Address that share the primary key employeeId in Employee table using @onetoOne annotions.My classes lool like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", catalog = "test", uniqueConstraints = {})
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private Integer employeeid;

    private String name;

    private Employeeaddress employeeaddress;
    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public Employee() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public Employee(Integer employeeid) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public Employee(Integer employeeid, String name) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Property accessors
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEEID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public Integer getEmployeeid() {
        return this.employeeid;
    }

    public void setEmployeeid(Integer employeeid) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME", unique = false, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 45)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="employee")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Employeeaddress getEmployeeaddress() {
        return employeeaddress;
    }

    public void setEmployeeaddress(Employeeaddress employeeaddress) {
        this.employeeaddress = employeeaddress;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "employeeaddress", catalog = "test", uniqueConstraints = {})
public class Employeeaddress implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private Integer employeeid;

    private String address;

    private Employee employee;
    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public Employeeaddress() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public Employeeaddress(Integer employeeid) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
    }

    /** full constructor */
    public Employeeaddress(Integer employeeid, String address) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
        this.address = address;
    }

    // Property accessors
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEEID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public Integer getEmployeeid() {
        return this.employeeid;
    }

    public void setEmployeeid(Integer employeeid) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
    }

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS", unique = false, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 45)
    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="employeeaddress")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

}
```

and my main class is

```
public class EmployeeDao {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        AnnotationConfiguration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(employeeforms.Employee.class);
        cfg.addAnnotatedClass(employeeforms.Employeeaddress.class);
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session =sessionFactory.openSession();
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setEmployeeid(100872);
        e.setName("sandeep");
        Employeeaddress ed = new Employeeaddress();     
        ed.setAddress("Hyderabad");
        e.setEmployeeaddress(ed);
        session.save(e);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

when i run my main class i get below exceptions

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1130)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1286)
    at employeeDao.EmployeeDao.main(EmployeeDao.java:16)
```

my tables are

```
    CREATE TABLE  employee (
      EMPLOYEEID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL ,
      NAME varchar(45) default '',
      PRIMARY KEY  (EMPLOYEEID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    CREATE TABLE  employeeaddress (
      EMPLOYEEID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
      ADDRESS varchar(45) default '',
      PRIMARY KEY  (EMPLOYEEID)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB 
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have (at least) three problems.

First problem: you specify

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="employee")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
```

and

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="employeeaddress")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
```

Those two annotations are contradictory; if `mappedBy` is set, it means that the mapping information is on the other side. Only one side should define the mapping (the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn)`, and the other side should set the `mappedBy` attribute.

Second problem: you specify

```
Employeeaddress ed = new Employeeaddress();     
ed.setAddress("Hyderabad");
e.setEmployeeaddress(ed);
```

Both sides of the associations should be initialized. The code should thus do:

```
e.setEmployeeaddress(ed);
ed.setEmployee(e);
```

Hibernate uses the side where mappedBy is **not** set to know if an association exists.

Third problem:

You save the employee, but don't save the address. And there is no cascade set from employee to address.

Comment: Thank u . for quick reply I will try and come back again and Godd explnation where you u cleared lot of doubts with one answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [these hibernate 3.6 docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html) your mapping should go like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", catalog = "test", uniqueConstraints = {})
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer employeeid;
    private Employeeaddress employeeaddress;
    // other fields and constructors

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEEID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public Integer getEmployeeid() {
        return this.employeeid;
    }

    public void setEmployeeid(Integer employeeid) {
        this.employeeid = employeeid;
    }


    @OneToOne(mappedBy="employee")
    public Employeeaddress getEmployeeaddress() {
        return employeeaddress;
    }

    public void setEmployeeaddress(Employeeaddress employeeaddress) {
        this.employeeaddress = employeeaddress;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "employeeaddress", catalog = "test", uniqueConstraints = {})
public class Employeeaddress implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer employeeid;
    private Employee employee;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEEID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public Integer getEmployeeid() {
        return this.employeeid;
    }
    // EDIT: private setter for employeeid, id is set by setEmployee() but hibernate needs a setter to initialize the instance on load
    private void setEmployeeid(Integer id) {
        this.employeeid = id;
    }


    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

}
```

EDIT:
The `@MapsId` annotation was introduced with JPA 2.0 (implemented in hibernate since 3.5 I think). If you are using an older hibernate version that does not implement the JPA 2.0 specification you can map the same id for two entities like this (class `Employee` remains unchanged):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employeeaddress", catalog = "test", uniqueConstraints = {})
public class Employeeaddress implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer employeeid;
    private Employee employee;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "anyName")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "anyName", strategy = "foreign", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "property", value = "employee") })
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEEID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public Integer getEmployeeid() {
        return this.employeeid;
    }
    // EDIT: private setter for employeeid, id is set by setEmployee() but hibernate needs a setter to initialize the instance on load
    private void setEmployeeid(Integer id) {
        this.employeeid = id;
    }   

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

}
```

You must also save the transient/detached `Employeeaddress` instance first before saving an associated transient/detached `Employee` instance or change the annotation in class `Employee` to cascading save:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="employee", cascade = CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
public Employeeaddress getEmployeeaddress() {
    return employeeaddress;
}
```

Comment: I still have problems.I am new to forum how to reply my questions,not as comment

Comment: @MapsId annotion does not exist in my class

Comment: @sandeep: What hibernate version are you using?

Comment: There is no @MapsId in JPA before 2.0 version, that's why it maybe does not exist.

Comment: @sandeep: added second version without `@MapsId` annotation.