# Hibernate 3 OneToOne working with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have a relationship: Client has an Account. So the following implementation is

Account.class:

```
@Column(name = "client_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign",
           parameters = { @Parameter(name = "property", value = "clientDTO") })
    private int client_id;
```

Client.class:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private AccountDTO accountDTO;
```

I init a Client, Account, and set account to the client, but when I try save it to db, I get an exception:

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into
>   public.accounts (balance, client_id, comment, credit_limit, id) values
>   (1000.0, 0, comment, 0.0, 8) was aborted.  Call getNextException to
>   see the cause.

As you see, my app tried to insert the account with client_id = 0;

How can I resolve it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want the account ID to have the same value as the client ID (without additional client_id column) or do you just want a plain one-to-one mapping where the account table has a client_id column? Please post your table definitions and the underlying database exception (from the postgresql log file).

Comment: try to query your DB directly with 'insert into public.accounts (balance, client_id, comment, credit_limit, id) values (1000.0, 0, comment, 0.0, 8)' and tell us what DB says in this case

Comment: @tscho I want to account's field "client_id", have the same value as a field "id". So one Client have one Account

Answer (score 1):

Use a java.lang.Integer instead of a primitive int-- that way Hibernate can tell that it hasn't been set yet, and needs to be generated (or passed as null). Or you can specify unsaved-value=0 (not sure how to do that from annotations though)

Comment: I have edited, and now here are another exception  ;)
 Batch entry 0 insert into public.clients (accountDTO_id, adress, type_id, comment, email, name, password, phone, id) values (15, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, name, password, NULL, 27) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430009/how-to-solve-jpa-and-hibernate-one-to-one-annotion-with-dosecondpass-exception/8430660#8430660). You don't need the extra `client_id` column in your `account` table if the value should be the same as the id of the `account` table. You can make the id of the account table the primary key **and** a foreign key referencing the `client` table.

And this is what your usage of `@GenericGenerator` with `strategy = 'foreign'` suggests, but you are missing the `@PrimaryJoinColumn` annotation. On top of this your `@OneToOne` property is on the wrong side. According to your exception the Account entity should reference a Client and not vice-versa.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I have been solved it. The main problem is the bi-directional relationship. So I had to set Account to Client, and Client to Acount. Thanks for all!